Rust Axum, binary type returned in handler fn
I have Axum handler which returns Vec<u8>, binary data. The result is often the same so I cache it using dashmap.  The issue is dashmap get gives me refrence, so to return it from Axum handler I need to always clone it first to have owned version bytes.clone(). Is it possible to not do it every time? Since I am only reading this data, why Axum needs owned version of it? Is it somehow moved into network socket or something like that? Also is unsafe rust something to get around that ? Or maybe I need to get around it with implementing my own IntoResponse.
I may be lacking some basic understanding here, sorry for that but any help highly appreciated.
How to reuse bytes stored in cache ?
Below example code:
use axum::{ extract::State, routing::get, Router };
use std::sync::Arc;
use dashmap::DashMap;

struct AppState {
    cache: DashMap<String, Vec<u8>>
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let cache: DashMap<String, Vec<u8>> = DashMap::new();
    let shared_state = Arc::new(AppState { cache });

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .with_state(shared_state);

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3001").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}

async fn handler(
    State(state): State<Arc<AppState>>,
) -> Vec<u8> {
    let cached = state.cache.get("test");
    if cached.is_some() {
        let bytes = cached.unwrap();
        println!("Cloned from cache!");
        return bytes.clone();
    }

    let data: Vec<u8> = vec![0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05,0x06];
    state.cache.insert("test".to_string(), data.clone());
    data
}


A good way to return bytes in a response that are also stored separately is to use Bytes. It is essentially a Arc<[u8]> but also supports owned subslices and a few other things.
Something like this is needed because a Response cannot reference non-static data. So a &[u8], even wrapped in a custom IntoResponse implementation wouldn't avoid a copy.
Using Bytes can already accomplish this with no copies and without lifetimes, but it also has direct integrations with axum. Bytes implements IntoResponse and is used for representing the body internally. It is available without additional dependency via axum::body::Bytes.
The conversion is relatively straightforward:
use axum::body::Bytes;
use axum::{extract::State, routing::get, Router};
use dashmap::DashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

struct AppState {
    cache: DashMap<String, Bytes>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let cache: DashMap<String, Bytes> = DashMap::new();
    let shared_state = Arc::new(AppState { cache });

    let app = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(handler))
        .with_state(shared_state);

    let listener = tokio::net::TcpListener::bind("0.0.0.0:3001").await.unwrap();
    axum::serve(listener, app).await.unwrap();
}

async fn handler(State(state): State<Arc<AppState>>) -> Bytes {
    let cached = state.cache.get("test");
    if cached.is_some() {
        let bytes = cached.unwrap();
        println!("Cloned from cache!");
        return bytes.clone();
    }

    let data = Bytes::from(vec![0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06]);
    state.cache.insert("test".to_string(), data.clone());
    data
}


The reason why axum needs an owned value (or, more precisely, a 'static-value) is that it needs to be able to keep that value for as long as axum is busy sending back the reply. If the value had a lifetime shorter than 'static (like any generic &[u8]), the compiler wouldn't be able to guarantee the code's safety.
Instead of cloning the entire buffer (Vec<u8>), you can simply put it into an Arc<[u8]>, and clone that. The Arc guarantees that the underlying data will be around for as long as at least one reference to it exists, but cloning the Arc is essentially free.

Prefer Bytes. It was designed for networking, and I believe it's also more efficient.
